# Does the UBC-C of this model: MSI Katana GF66 11UE support mobile monitor connection?

Tags: monitors, usb-c

Does the UBC-C of this model: MSI Katana GF66 11UE support mobile monitor connection? In other words does its USB-C send only current or also signal, in order to support an external connection with a mobile monitor?